# For loop in bash scripting

Tags: shell-script

The following for loop in bash gives an error -

```
line 42: 1
2
3
4
5 + 1: syntax error in expression (error token is "2
3
4
5 + 1")
```

line 42 is statement - **num1=$[$i1 + 1]**

```
for i1 in `seq 1 5`
    do
    num1=$[$i1 + 1]
        for k1 in `seq $num1 5`
        do
        ky1="${team_two[i1]}_${team_two[k1]}"
        pair_score[$ky1]=$[${pair_score[$ky1]}+1]
        done
    done
```

What is wrong with the code?

**EDIT**
I get the following output on debugging

```
++ seq 1 5
+ for i1 in '`seq 1 5`'
/home/ashwin/bin/calculate_power: line 43: 1
2
3
4
5 + 1: syntax error in expression (error token is "2
3
4
5 + 1")
```

Again it is the same statement that line 43 - **num1=$[$i+1]**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have some problems with your `${team_two[*]}` & `${team_two[k1]}` arrays or you've messed with the separation characters in the special variable `$IFS`. You can turn the Bash debugging on by adding a `set -x` before you enter the outer for loop. And then disable it afterwards with a `set +x`, to gain further insights.

```
set -x
... for loop block ...
set +x
```

#### Example

When I run your code through Bash in this manner I get the following output:

```
$ bash -x for.bash 
++ seq 1 5
+ for i1 in '`seq 1 5`'
+ num1=2
++ seq 2 5
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=1
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=2
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=3
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=4
+ for i1 in '`seq 1 5`'
+ num1=3
++ seq 3 5
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=5
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=6
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=7
+ for i1 in '`seq 1 5`'
+ num1=4
++ seq 4 5
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=8
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=9
+ for i1 in '`seq 1 5`'
+ num1=5
++ seq 5 5
+ for k1 in '`seq $num1 5`'
+ ky1=_
+ pair_score[$ky1]=10
+ for i1 in '`seq 1 5`'
+ num1=6
++ seq 6 5
```

#### Edit #1

After further updates it would appear you've reset `$IFS`. Typically you'll want to save `$IFS` to an secondary variable prior to reseting it, and the revert it later on back to it's original value.

```
IFSOLD=$IFS
IFS=,

... do IFS , stuff here ...

IFS=$IFSOLD
```

#### IFS

If you try these examples they might help shed additional light on to the impact `$IFS` can play when used within a script.

Say I have the following variable:

```
$ var="1,2,3,4,5"
```

Now let's parse it and print the first variable, `$c1`:

```
$ IFS=',' read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 <<< "$var"
$ echo "$c1"
1
```

However if we changed our `$IFS` to a space.

```
$ IFS=' ' read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 <<< "$var"
$ echo "$c1"
1,2,3,4,5
```

So in the second example, we've configured the `read` command via `$IFS` to split on spaces, rather than commas.

Comment: I did the debugging as you told. I have edited the question with the output.

Comment: If the problem was with the arrays then echo "$num1" should atleast have worked. But even that doesn't work

Comment: @Ashwin - what version of Bash is this? It looks as if it's trying to add all the elements. `1 2 3 4 5 + 1`.

Comment: Bash version - 4.2.45(1)

Comment: @Ashwin see updates.

Comment: how does IFS value affect a for loop?

Comment: @Ashwin - with `$IFS` set to a comma the shell will not be able to part the output of `seq 1 5` as 5 individual atoms but rather a single atom.

Comment: @Ashwin - let me know if the additional example helps.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing (fundamentally) wrong with that code, your problem is you've reset "IFS" somewhere else, it's probably *empty* (so the output of `seq` is treated as a single token).

*Long* time since I've seen `$[]`, it's [obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415724/bash-arithmetic-expression-vs-arithmetic-expression) (and undocumented). Use `$(( ))`.

Instead of `seq` use `for (( ))`, and instead of adding 1, use `let var++`, so we have:

```
for (( i1=1 ; i1<=5; i1++))
    do
        for ((k1=i1+1; k1<=5; k1++))
            do
                ky1="${team_two[i1]}_${team_two[k1]}"
                let pair_score[$ky1]++
            done
    done
```

Since you're using a recent bash with associative arrays, may as well use the other nice features too :-)

Comment: you are right about the IFS part. I have set the "IFS=,". That was done because I wanted to split a string into an array separated by comma. What does that have to do with for loop seq? How can I correct it?